# How to edit a file descriptor in place with sed

Tags: bash, sed, sh, file-descriptor

I succeeded in using a file descriptor with sed and giving the result on the standard output. Giving a file "file.txt" containing :

```
$ cat file.txt
foo
Foo
```

I open a file descriptor to file.txt, open a sub-shell, and give this file descriptor to sed :

```
$ (sed "/Foo/c\\bar" <&9 ) 9< file.txt
foo
bar
```

The result is correct.

Now, if I want to use the -i option of sed to change in place, I have troubles. I open the file descriptor in read and write mode, then give it to sed as input file :

```
$ (sed -i "/Foo/c\\bar" <&9 ) 9<> file.txt
sed: no input file
```

I do not understand why an input file is missing. Maybe sed needs a filename, and not a file descriptor when using the -i option ?

I tried a workaround which, of course, does not work as expected :

```
$ (sed "/Foo/c\\bar" <&9 >&9 ) 9<> file.txt
$ cat file.txt
foo
Foo
foo
bar
```

while I expected :

```
$ cat file.txt
foo
bar
```

Thanks in advance for your help !
Dunatotatos

Comment: What's the actual problem you're trying to solve? I mean, it's *possible* to slurp the file's contents into a shell variable (as long as it has no NULs), seek to the beginning of the FD (albeit using either external tools or a shell plugin written in C, as there's no seek builtin in bash), and then rewrite, but it's fragile and inefficient and there's almost certainly a better way.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As I manage concurrent processes, I need to lock the access to the file.txt to get an exclusive access. To reach the goal, I use this pattern : `( flock -x 9 ; sed -i "/Foo/c\\bar" <&9 ) 9< file.txt ` I try to solve this line not working.

Comment: Ahh! `sed -i` will actually break your locking in that case; you can't use it on the file for which the lock is held. Instead, you should use a **different** file for your lock; for instance, to control access to file `foo`, lock `.foo.lck`. (There are various other precautions necessary to avoid races -- would need to review a script in full context to declare all its practices safe).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Actually, I realized my mistake when I saw my processes were still not happy after my modification. You're right on all of your comments. Let's use an independent lock file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -i` expects a filename. You can't pass `/dev/stdin` (or similar), as sed will attempt to create a temporary file inside `/dev`.

You can't even save the output of `sed` into a temporary file and then write the output in the file descriptor again, as you can't rewind a file descriptor in Bash.

What you can do is figure out the original file name from the file descriptor. You can do this by using the link `/proc/self/fd/9`, like this:

```
sed -i "/Foo/c\\bar" "$(readlink /proc/self/fd/9)"
```

However, note that the original file may have been deleted or renamed, in which case this solution won't work. Also, this solution expects `/proc` to be available, which might not always be the case. `/dev/fd/9` may be a good replacement.

Another thing to be aware of is that `sed -i` works by replacing the the file with a new one: after running `sed -i`, your fd 9 won't refer the newly created file. To workaround this problem:

```
name="$(readlink /proc/self/fd/9)"
cp "$name" "$name.tmp"
sed "/Foo/c\\bar" "$name.tmp" > "$name"
```

This way, your fd 9 will still refer the same file before and after running `sed`. You might want to use `mktemp` to create the temporary file, and `atexit` to ensure that it gets deleted.

Comment: This answer exactly matches my expectations. As I use this pattern to manage parallel processes, I already use flock to get an exclusive lock on the file attached to the file descriptor. So, no risk the file is deleted or renamed. Thank you for your help and explanations.

Comment: @Dunatotatos, ...if your code is what's calling flock and opening the FD, then this answer adds nothing at all over simply reusing the variable name you passed to give flock the file to open. It's still a separate descriptor in both cases. (Also, re: "no risk the file is deleted or renamed" -- an exclusive *advisory* lock, as returned by `flock`, does not prevent those things; it only prevents a separate program from getting an exclusive lock on the same inode).

Comment: @Dunatotatos, ...the other thing to look into is whether your implementation of `sed -i` rewrites the existing inode's contents in place or does a create-and-rename swap; if it does the latter (which, as it allows for atomic replacement, is typically preferred), then after the operation of `sed` the directory entry will point to a file with a different inode, **not** the one your lock is held on, so other programs will be able to grab a lock on that descriptor even if your script is still running.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As said above, your comments are right. I'll use a lock file. But I keep this answer as correct answer, as it exactly answers my initial question. Thank you :)

Comment: BTW, `/dev/fd` is typically implemented as a link to `/proc/self/fd` -- I wouldn't expect it to function when the other is not present, except for shell builtins (where it may have special treatment); `readlink`, however, is not such.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: true, but that's not always the case. That why it "may be" a replacement

Comment: @Dunatotatos: I've updated my answer to fit your use case

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Perfect ! Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

You cannot edit anything "in place" with sed, and this is a great example of why `-i` is misnamed.  gnu sed implements `-i` by creating a new file, writing the output to it, and then renaming the file.  If you don't give sed the original filename, it doesn't know what to rename it.

Comment: This is exceptionally important because it means that the OP's goal, of maintaining a lock on a file through the process of editing it, is incompatible with their methods.